# AWS S3 - Listing all objects inside a folder without the prefix

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having problems retrieving all objects (filenames) inside a folder in AWS S3. Here's my code:

```java
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName(bucket)
            .withPrefix(folderName + "/")
            .withMarker(folderName + "/")

ObjectListing objectListing = amazonWebService.s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)

for (S3ObjectSummary summary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    print summary.getKey()
}
```

It returns the correct object but with the prefix in it, e.g. `foldename/filename`

I know I can just use Java perhaps `substring` to exclude the prefix but I just wanted to know if there is a method for it in AWS SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not. Linked is a list of all the methods that are available. The reason behind this is the S3 design. S3 does not have "subfolders". Instead it is simply a list of files, where the filename is the "prefix" plus the filename you desire. The GUI shows the data similar to windows stored in "folders", but there is not folder logic present in S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html

Your best bet is to split by "/" and to take the last object in the array.

Answer (score 5):

For Scala developers, here it is recursive function to execute a ***full scan and map*** of the contents of an AmazonS3 bucket using the official [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{S3ObjectSummary, ObjectListing, GetObjectRequest}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{collectionAsScalaIterable => asScala}

def map[T](s3: AmazonS3Client, bucket: String, prefix: String)(f: (S3ObjectSummary) => T) = {

  def scan(acc:List[T], listing:ObjectListing): List[T] = {
    val summaries = asScala[S3ObjectSummary](listing.getObjectSummaries())
    val mapped = (for (summary <- summaries) yield f(summary)).toList

    if (!listing.isTruncated) mapped.toList
    else scan(acc ::: mapped, s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))
  }

  scan(List(), s3.listObjects(bucket, prefix))
}
```

To invoke the above curried `map()` function, simply pass the already constructed (and properly initialized) AmazonS3Client object (refer to the official [AWS SDK for Java API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)), the bucket name and the prefix name in the first parameter list. Also pass the function `f()` you want to apply to map each object summary in the second parameter list.

For example

```scala
map(s3, bucket, prefix) { s => println(s.getKey.split("/")(1)) }
```

will print all the filenames (without the prefix)

```scala
val tuple = map(s3, bucket, prefix)(s => (s.getKey, s.getOwner, s.getSize))
```

will return the full list of `(key, owner, size)` tuples in that bucket/prefix

```scala
val totalSize = map(s3, "bucket", "prefix")(s => s.getSize).sum
```

will return the total size of its content (note the additional `sum()` folding function applied at the end of the expression ;-)

You can combine `map()` with many other functions as you would normally approach by [Monads in Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)

Comment: There is an error in this solution. If S3 returns multiple batches this function will only return the result of mapping over the last.

One fix is to remove the accumulator parameter from scan and change the conditional to:

if (!listing.isTruncated) mapped.toList
else mapped ::: scan(s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your comment. This was crucial to a production project and I didn't catch Paolo's mistake in his initial function. With the accumulator it isn't recursing properly, and it will cascade returning only the final result, versus recursing and appending each scan to the final result.

Answer (score 4):

This code help me to find sub-directory of my bucket.

Example :- "Testing" is a my bucket name , inside that contain "kdblue@gmail.com " folder then its contain "IMAGE" folder in which contain image files.

```
     ArrayList<String> transferRecord = new ArrayList<>();    

     ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest =
                            new ListObjectsRequest()
                                    .withBucketName(Constants.BUCKET_NAME)
                                    .withPrefix("kdblue@gmail.com" + "/IMAGE");

      ObjectListing objects = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        for (;;) {
                    List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = 
                    objects.getObjectSummaries();
                        if (summaries.size() < 1) {
                            break;
                        }

                       for(int i=0;i<summaries.size();i++){
                            ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<>();

                            file.add(summaries.get(i).getKey());
                            transferRecord.add(file);
                        }

                        objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
               }
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Just to follow up on the comment above - "here it is recursive function to execute a full scan and map" - there is a bug in the code (as @Eric highlighted) if there are more than 1000 keys in the bucket. The fix is actually quite simple, the mapped.toList needs to be merged with acc.

```
def map[T](s3: AmazonS3Client, bucket: String, prefix: String)(f: (S3ObjectSummary) => T) = {

  def scan_s3_bucket(acc:List[T], listing:ObjectListing): List[T] = {
    val summaries = asScala[S3ObjectSummary](listing.getObjectSummaries())
    val mapped = (for (summary <- summaries) yield f(summary)).toList

    if (!listing.isTruncated) {
      acc ::: mapped.toList
    } else {
      println("list extended, more to go: new_keys '%s', current_length '%s'".format(mapped.length, acc.length))
      scan_s3_bucket(acc ::: mapped, s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))
    }
  }

  scan_s3_bucket(List(), s3.listObjects(bucket, prefix))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below snipped worked quite well for me. Reference: https://codeflex.co/get-list-of-objects-from-s3-directory/

```
    List<String> getObjectslistFromFolder(String bucketName, String folderKey, AmazonS3 s3Client) {

    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName)
            .withPrefix(folderKey + "/");

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
    for (;;) {
        List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = objects.getObjectSummaries();
        if (summaries.size() < 1) {
            break;
        }

        // summaries.forEach(s -> keys.add(s.getKey()));
        // changed project compliance to jre 1.8
        summaries.forEach(s -> keys.add(s.getKey()));

        objects = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
    }

    return keys;
```