# AWS- S3 bucket list object where key contains a string

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 10k files in my s3 bucket and I want to list only those files whose key contains a specific string.

for eg. there are 5 keys in s3 bucket 

`abc_test_one.mp3
abc_test_two.mp3
abc_test1_one.mp3
abc_test2_one.mp3
abc_test_three.mp3`

Here I want retrieve only those key whose name contains `test` in key name.
Please suggest some solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to retrieve list of objects ? which is contain in bucket?

Comment: yes list of object which are containing the string 'test' in key name.

Comment: check this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114784/6925888 , i retrieve all object in particular bucket .